# Thinking Sphinx: indexing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, thinking-sphinx

ANSWERED:
set_primary_key "QTLID" in the model to tell model that pirmary ID is not ID

I am getting this error when I rake:ts index

```
Cannot automatically map attribute sphinx_internal_id in QtlTable to an
equivalent Sphinx type (integer, float, boolean, datetime, string as ordinal).
You could try to explicitly convert the column's value in your define_index
block:
  has "CAST(column AS INT)", :type => :integer, :as => :column
```

I can't figure out how to fix this.

Here is my model (note I did not setup this database so don't jump on me for terrible conventions):

```
class QtlTable < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
    define_index do
      indexes :QTLID
      has :QTLName
    end    
end
```

Here is what schema looks like for qtl_table:

```
create_table "qtl_table", :primary_key => "QTLID", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "QTLName",                     :limit => 60,       :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "Parent_1",                    :limit => 60,       :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "Parent_2",                    :limit => 60,       :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "Heritability",                :limit => 60,       :default => ""
  t.text   "Population_size",             :limit => 16777215
  t.string "Number_plants_bulked",        :limit => 10
  t.text   "Pop_high_score",              :limit => 16777215
  t.text   "Pop_low_score",               :limit => 16777215
  t.string "Loci_tested",                 :limit => 10,       :default => ""
  t.string "Intervals_associated",        :limit => 10,       :default => ""
  t.string "Interval_length",             :limit => 6,        :default => ""
  t.string "Interval_LOD_score",          :limit => 12,       :default => ""
  t.string "Interval_P_value",            :limit => 6,        :default => ""
  t.string "Interval_R2",                 :limit => 6,        :default => ""
  t.string "Genotypic_R2",                :limit => 6,        :default => ""
  t.text   "R2_Definition",               :limit => 16777215
  t.string "Percent_variation_explained", :limit => 6,        :default => ""
  t.string "First_entered",               :limit => 60,       :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "Last_update",                 :limit => 60,       :default => ""
  t.string "TraitName",                   :limit => 100,      :default => ""
  t.binary "in_new",                      :limit => 1
end

add_index "qtl_table", ["QTLName"], :name => "QTLName_index"
add_index "qtl_table", ["TraitName"], :name => "TraitName_index"
```

ANSWERED:
set_primary_key "QTLID" in the model to tell model that pirmary ID is not ID

Comment: ANSWERED:


set_primary_key "QTLID" in the model to tell model that pirmary ID is not ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set_primary_key "QTLID" in the model to tell model that pirmary ID is not ID